# ErrorException Array to string conversion Laravel 6.0 EmailVerification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I just upgraded my laravel app from 5.8 to 6, but I'm unable to get my Email Verification to work properly. I keep getting error when I click the verification link that was sent to the email.

I keep getting Error `ErrorException Array to string conversion` which points to Line 35 of `project_root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails.php`

Line 35

```
  if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
       throw new AuthorizationException;
  }
```

I don't understand how to resolve this. Please I need assistance on this

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: you can use toArray() after  $request->user()->getKey()->toArray()

Comment: And based on the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#email-verification-route) this has been changed to POST route instead of GET so make sure that you follow that as well.

Comment: Yes I have added a form to use POST for the link verification

Comment: @vikas, you mean I should edit the VerifiesEmail.php

Comment: yes you have edit in  VerifiesEmail.php.

Comment: @vikas, I edited VerifiesEmail.php as you suggested, but It did not work. Same error

Comment: I hash all {id} implicit route model binding throughout the app. The error was caused because I did not hash id key invendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php : verificationUrl()